# HttpClient5.0, How to use gzip in asynchronous mode?

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-5.x

HttpClient5.0.1, How to use gzip in asynchronous mode?
There is no example of using gzip compression in asynchronous mode on the official document.

Answer (score 1):

Apache HttpAsyncClient version 4.1 and 5.0 presently do not support automatic content decompression.